# DevExpress GridView s.GetSelectedFieldValues function not being called

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I have a DevExpress MVC GridView where I want to handle the SelectionChanged event *solely on the client side*, and wire any postings to the server myself using AJAX.

My GridView calls my `SelectionChanged()` function, but the code `s.GetSelectedFieldValues("MedicalRecordNumber", GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback);` within that function seems to do nothing, and `GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback(values)` is not called.

Here's my GridView partial view, it has no markkup...

```
@model IEnumerable<CaseReview>

@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "workListTable";
    settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(90);
    settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSort = true;
    settings.Settings.ShowFilterRow = true;
    settings.KeyFieldName = "UUID";
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "CaseReviewID";
        column.Caption = "CaseReviewID";
        column.CellStyle.CssClass = "devExCaseIdHidden";
    });
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "FacilityName";
        column.Caption = "FacilityName";
    });
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "MedicalRecordNumber";
        column.Caption = "Medical Record Number";
    });
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "DateOfBirth";
        column.Caption = "DateOrBirth";
    });
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "AgeInYears";
        column.Caption = "AgeInYears";
    });
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "Sex";
        column.Caption = "Sex";
    });
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "AdmitDate";
        column.Caption = "AdmitDate";
    });
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "LOS";
        column.Caption = "LOS";
    });
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "DischargeStatus";
        column.Caption = "DischargeStatus";
    });
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "ROM";
        column.Caption = "ROM";
    });
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "SOI";
        column.Caption = "SOI";
    });
    settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "Category";
        column.Caption = "Category";
    });
    settings.CommandColumn.ShowSelectCheckbox = true;
    settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
    settings.ClientSideEvents.SelectionChanged = "SelectionChanged";
    settings.ClientSideEvents.RowDblClick = "function(s, e) { OnRowClick(s, e); }";
}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

...and here's the relevant bit of Javascript...

```
function SelectionChanged(s, e) {
    s.GetSelectedFieldValues("MedicalRecordNumber", GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback);
    alert("new row selected");
}

function GetSelectedFieldValuesCallback(values) {
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var item = values[i];
    }
}
```

As I said the GetSelectedVieldValuesCallback(values) function is not called, and returns `undefined`. I'm following the example presented [here](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/Selection/RowSelection) very closely.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to implement **settings.CallbackRouteValues** mode.

Check [this](https://www.devexpress.com/kbid=KA20010) KB to learn more on how to proceed.